# How to solve the TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

When am run test case am getting the following issue.

## Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

## Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'enzyme';
import FileUpload from '../Components/Elements/fileUpload';

describe('FileUpload component', ()=>{
    const wrapper = render(<FileUpload />);
    it('Test init status', function() {
        expect(wrapper.find('input').length).toBe(2);
        expect(wrapper.find('input').text()).toEqual('');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us FileUpload component?

Comment: A quote on how this has been solved would be great. Thanks

Comment: I'm also seeing this same error  - any insight would be appreciated :)